# Where to start learning Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want to make an app, however I cannot use Java or Swift.

Fortunately, I found that I can make apps with **Python** and **Kivy**

I read a recommended tutorial book : **OReilly Creating Apps in Kivy (2014)**.

However, the Kivy version in the book is 1.8, the Kivy version is 1.11 nowadyas,

something will be wrong when I test the codes such as ListView ...

Additionally, I discovered that this book integrates python and kv file to make an app.

Many people say that it is better to make an app in **pure python**.

Hence, I have no idea where I can start to learn Kivy

Can anyone give me some adive ?

Should I continue to learn Kivy with that book ?

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your question carefully and found solution too.

Personally, I am from India. In our country, people who want to learn Technology or programming, they generally prefer **YouTube**. You can use YouTube too for learning or finding small 2-3 hour courses on Kivy 1.11.

Also, go to this official Kivy.org link to start with a small [crash course](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/tutorials/crashcourse.html)

Using book for learning new programming language is typically a boring task. Instead, listen to **podcasts** and watch videos on **YouTube** to learn some basics (some starter)

Also, if you are serious enough about learning Kivy, why not to use **Udemy or Coursera**? Almost every course is available on these both platform.

It finally depends on you to choose a best source for learning. Also make sure that you have enough basic knowledge about Python to get started with Kivy.

Have a nice day!

Comment: I recommend you avoid answering these types of questions since they are off-topic here, read [ask] and [answer]